# What does $.function(){} do in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If doing this `$(function(){})` is short hand for `$(document).ready(function() {});` used to ensure that it is called once all the DOM elements of the page is loaded.

What does `$.function(){}` do?

Comment: Nothing? I don't think that's even syntactically valid. Did you see it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, i came across the question online and i just couldn't figure it out. I guess it's just a tricky question.

Comment: There's not much to it: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`. Not a tricky question, rather a trick question at best. However, if you insert a linebreak between `)` and `{`, things change…

Comment: I'd counter with another question: what makes you think that is valid JavaScript?

Comment: `$.function` is undefined. `$.fn` on the other hand is used to extend the main jQuery object.